# Is it possible to create a grails app that uses mongoDB (or any other database) on a docker container as the datasource?

Tags: database, mongodb, docker, grails, groovy

How can I connect to a mongodb database which is located on a docker container from my grails app?

Any help would be appreciated. If there is an example somewhere of this being done with another database instead of mongo that would help me out too as I'm sure I could just switch out the credentials for my mongo database. But the main factors are connecting to a database hosted on a docker container from a grails app.

Thanks

Comment: As far as Groovy and Grails are concerned, I don't think the fact that MongoDB is running in a docker container is of any consequence.  The app just needs to be told what machine and port the db is running on and doesn't need to know if that is local, remote, in a container, or whatever.

Comment: Please rewrite your question to show your actual problem.  Don't ask
what is possible but what you have tried and how it failed.