# How to use more than one grails profile?

Tags: grails, groovy

I want to create a grails app that uses both REST-API profile and the Angular profile.

Is this possible? It seems like it must be because Angular is so often used with REST-APIs, but I can't find any documentation on using more than one profile online.

Comment: When you generate an app with the angular profile a `client` subproject is created with the SPA code in it and a `server` subproject is created that is setup to support being a REST backend for the SPA.  Is that what you want or do you explicitly want to call out `rest-api` in your `build.gradle` for some reason?

Comment: No, that is what I want to do. I'm very new to grails so I don't think I was understanding the point of profiles when I created this question, but that sounds right - I am just looking for an angular front end and a grails backend that supports REST endpoints. I will get all that with the Angular profile? 

Thanks

Comment: Yes.  There is some relevant info at https://guides.grails.org/angular2-combined/guide/index.html.

Comment: Thank you very much - another question I had I posted but got no responses - do you know how I can connect this grails app to a database that is hosted in a docker container? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67892808/is-it-possible-to-create-a-grails-app-that-uses-mongodb-or-any-other-database

Comment: I left a comment on that issue.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.